# Optimally sampling n rows from location Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, sample

I have a dataframe of latitudes and longitudes. I want to get a sample of size n_samples that covers the majority of the region in the dataframe. At first, I wanted to first sort the dataframe by latitude and longitude and then use modular arithmetic to select evenly spread-out rows. However, this does not work in cases where I wish to sample, say, 27 out of 100 rows, since 100 % 27 is not 0. Note this problem gets even worse when trying to use n_sample=80 (since it would sample all 100 rows). So it will not be useful to simply adjust the number of rows afterward.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

n_samples = 27
lat = [random.uniform(30, 50) for i in range(100)]
lon = [random.uniform(-130, -100) for i in range(100)]

loc_df = pd.DataFrame([lat, lon]).T
loc_df.columns = ['lat', 'lon']

# Sort loc_df by lat/lon
loc_df = loc_df.sort_values(['lat', 'lon'])

# Sample every n rows 
# Tends to sample either too many or too few rows
# In this case, we will be sampling 24 instead of 27 rows

every_n = round(loc_df.shape[0]/n_samples) 
sample_df = loc_df[::every_n].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is 'train_test_split' from sklearn.

```html
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

test_pct = 1 - (n_samples / len(loc_df))


X = loc_df.iloc[:,0]
Y = loc_df.iloc[:,1]

X_sample, X_remain, Y_sample, Y_remain = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size=test_pct, random_state=0)

sample_df = X_sample.to_frame().join(Y_sample).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This assigns a test_pct variable based on your n_samples and the size of the dataframe

Create X (lat) and Y(lon) arrays from your loc_df

Use "train_test_split" to randomly select your "n_samples"

and then create your sample_df dataframe containing "n_samples" of data.

Will that work for your purposes?

Comment: I believe that this is too random for the purpose of the question (as equally spaced as possible). Maybe some iterative process where you start with random sampling and then measuring the diff vector between all sample indices (do not forget to add the edges), and then at any iteration reducing by 1 values that are larger than the median and increasing any  that are smaller than the median, till optimum... Or something in that spirit.